# Powerline in vim errors setting up

Tags: vim, vimrc

I installed powerline using pip install as per their installation recommendations.
I have it working fine in both zsh as a prompt and tmux as a statusline yet I can't get it to work in vim.

When I add the following to my vimrc:

```
python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python powerline_setup()
python del powerline_setup
```

I get the following errors

```
Error detected while processing /home/jordan/.vimrc:
line    1:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
line    2:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: python powerline_setup()
line    3:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: python del powerline_setup
```

EDIT: After checking that my version of vim (vim.gnome) is compiled with python support I noticed it is (python3). So I changed the vimrc to use python3 as per the installation instructions and get the following:

```
Error detected while processing /home/jordan/.vimrc:
line    1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'powerline'
line    2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'powerline_setup' is not defined
line    3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'powerline_setup' is not defined
```

Any ideas, im at my wits end with this!

SOLVED EDIT: I was unable to get it to work with python3 but it seems that is the only version of python supported in vim.gnome and vim.basic.

I installed vim.nox `apt install vim-nox-py2` with python 2 support and it all works. 
Hopefully this solves somebody else a headache.

Answer (score 15):

I fixed it as follows:

1. edit `~/.vimrc` and change`python` to `python3` in each of the 3 lines in the original question above
2. `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
3. `pip3 install --user powerline-status`

Comment: The part `pip3 install --user powerline-status` was enough for me, thanks.